# Controls not rendering in modeless dialog box MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

**UPDATE**: Possible solution. Declaring the CWait dialog in the header seems to solve this.

**UPDATE2:** Message pump may be the culprit. Explicit "pumping" seems to resolve problem.

Im trying to display a modal "Please Wait" Dialog box while some functions execute in an application. The dialog I want to display is this:
[image]

Im using this code to call the dialog box.

```
CWait dialog;
dialog.Create(IDD_WAIT);
dialog.SetWindowTextW(L"Geocoding");
dialog.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

mastImageGeocode(); //Working here
slvImageGeocode();
interfImageGeocode();
cohImageGeocode();

dialog.CloseWindow();
```

What ends up displaying is this:
[image]

I cant seem to figure out why the controls don't render.

I tried manually processing the message loop after initialization of the dialog with this approach:

```
MSG stMsg;

             while (::PeekMessage (&stMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) 
            {
            ::TranslateMessage (&stMsg);
            ::DispatchMessage (&stMsg);
            }
```

Did not really work.

I also tried the pointer approach

```
Cwait * dialog; //THis is in header
dialog = new CWait(this);
dialog->Create(IDD_WAIT);
dialog->SetWindowTextW(L"Geocoding");
dialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

mastImageGeocode(); //Some work here
slvImageGeocode();
interfImageGeocode();
cohImageGeocode();

dialog->CloseWindow();
delete dialog;
```

Am I doing something wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Update: If I call it inside the individual functions, it works fine!

Comment: As a quick test, does dialog.ShowModal(); work okay?

Comment: @JBRWilkinson You mean doModal() right? `CWait dialog;
 
 dialog.DoModal();` does work for me.

Comment: If I put the same code in each of the 3 functions, it works once and doesnt work the next time (display)

Comment: UPDATE: Possible solution. Declaring the CWait dialog in the header seems to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

m_progressBar.SetPos(Progress+1);

m_progressBar.SetPos(Progress);

and it will show. Don't ask me why ...
PS.: attention when reaching the last Progressstep!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not updating your dialog from your main processing loop.  I've put a  cut down version of my MFC progress dialog below.  Note that it is necessary to call **SetProgress** regularly to update the screen.  As a more general point, if you're using modeless dialogs in MFC, you need to call **OnUpdate(FALSE)** for them to refresh, and ensure they have enough time to do so.  Quite often when I think I need a modeless dialog, I'm actually served better by splitting the task into separate threads, i.e. the processing part gets placed in its own worker thread.  YMMV.

```
class CProgressDialog : public CDialog
{
public:
    CProgressDialog(LPCTSTR Name,int Max,CWnd* pParent = NULL);  
    CProgressDialog(UINT NameID,int Max,CWnd* pParent = NULL);   
    virtual ~CProgressDialog();

    int m_Max;
    void SetProgress(int Progress);
    void SetRange(int Range);
    enum { IDD = IDD_PROGRESS_DIALOG };
    CProgressCtrl   m_Progress;
    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);  
protected:
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};


CProgressDialog::CProgressDialog(LPCTSTR Name,int Max,CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CProgressDialog::IDD, pParent)
{
    Create(CProgressDialog::IDD, pParent);
    SetWindowPos(&wndTop,1,1,0,0,SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    SetWindowText(Name);
    m_Max = Max;
}


CProgressDialog::~CProgressDialog()
{
    DestroyWindow();    
}

void CProgressDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_PROGRESS, m_Progress);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CProgressDialog, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CProgressDialog::OnInitDialog() 
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    m_Progress.SetRange32(0,m_Max);
    return TRUE; 
}

void CProgressDialog::SetProgress(int Progress) 
{
    m_Progress.SetRange32(0,m_Max);
    m_Progress.SetPos(Progress);
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}

void CProgressDialog::SetRange(int Range) 
{
    m_Max = Range;
}
```

Comment: I see a few mistakes that I am making from your code. Thanks! I haven't made a threaded program yet. Any good link to ease into a multi thread workflow? (Id really like to learn that)

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually pump messages not just at the beginning of the dialog, but after updates as well. 
Something like this:

```
void CProgressDialog::SetProgress(int Progress) 
{
    m_progressBar.SetPos(Progress);

    MSG msg;
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```